# How to display a large preview of (my own) flash player in the new timeline?

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-opengraph, highlight, preview

I got my own flash player on my website, and share my video on Facebook using the Open Graph Meta Tags. How to display a large preview of my video when the post is highlighted like Youtube Video?

Exemple: https://www.facebook.com/LouisVuitton/timeline/2011

To display the large preview of a Youtube video, highlight the post with the star. But when I share a video using my own flash player, and star the post, I get a small preview on the left and the description.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to post your video to facebook. Are you using the javascript SDK FB.ui.feed ?

Comment: @Plastic Sturgeon: The only code involved are open graph tags on a link you paste in Facebook's status update box. It's that simple. I have mimicked every tag youtube has, except for `fb:app_id` (it won't, predictably enough, allow me to). This leads me to believe it's preferencial treatment.

Comment: I think it's indeed a specific treatment. And bad at it since it's buggy...

Comment: Can i check your current site ?

Comment: I posted a bug report here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/125007077653194. Please subscribe to help raise attention :)

Answer (score 2):

One of the things you can do is use their Open Graph tester, found at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.  I have noticed that the image is what they will show, with a placeholder play button, until play is clicked.  Then your width and height settings in your Open Graph meta tags kick in.  Make sure when running the tester that the image actually appears in the "Object Properties" section, and that you clear as many warnings as possible.  Unfortunately, some warnings can't be cleared, like if you have Twitter Open Graph tags (Facebook doesn't like those).
Try to add as much info as possible, and follow the Open Graph protocol, at http://ogp.me/.  You can add meta tags inside your actual page body as well (not just in the head) for Open Graph, but the meta tag is different inside than a normal Meta tag.  That messed me up for awhile.  The better you follow the standard, the better Facebook will respond.
Also, don't forget to set up the Open Graph in your App on Facebook. (https://developers.facebook.com/apps) Make sure you edit the "Open Graph" section of your app and add as much info there as possible, too.
Personally, I liked the old rest posting, because you could force the preview height and width, but such is progress.